# How can I do role based authorization in React?

Tags: reactjs, authorization, redux-toolkit

I am making a react application. I show my menu items from the application according to the user's role. But if I manually enter the link that I do not see in the menu, I can view the page. How do I solve this problem? I want to return a 401 page if the user does not have permission to go to the page, how can I do it?

```
export function MainLayout() {
    const { userToken, userInfo, loading } = useSelector((state) => state.auth);
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const [selectedMenu, setselectedMenu] = useState(null)
    const [selectedSub, setselectedSub] = useState(null)
    const [pageTitle, setpageTitle] = useState('');
    const intl = useIntl();
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const location = useLocation();
    let userRole = '';
    if (userToken) {
        const token = localStorage.getItem('userToken');
        const sub = getTokenSub(token);
        userRole = getRole(token);
        const getUser = { id: sub };
        const fetchData = async () => {
            await dispatch(getUserById(getUser));
        }
        useEffect(() => {
            fetchData();
            const selectedKey = localStorage.getItem("selectedMenuKey");
            const selectedSub = localStorage.getItem("selectedSub");
            if (selectedKey) {
                setselectedMenu(selectedKey);
                setselectedSub(selectedSub);
            }
        }, []);
        useEffect(() => {
            setpageTitle(document.title);
        }, [location]);
    }
    const menuItemClick = (e) => {
        let selectedKey = e.key;
        let selectedSub = e.keyPath[1];
        localStorage.setItem("selectedMenuKey", selectedKey);
        localStorage.setItem("selectedSub", selectedSub);
        switch (selectedKey) {
            case "menu_create_client":
                navigate("/client/create")
                break;
            case "menu_city_list":
                navigate("/city/list")
                break;
            case "menu_country_list":
                navigate("/country/list")
                break;
            case "menu_my_account":
                navigate("/myprofile")
                break;
            case "menu_logout":
                handleLogout()
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
    const handleLogout = () => {
        dispatch(signOut())
        localStorage.removeItem('selectedMenuKey');
        localStorage.removeItem('selectedSub');
        navigate('/login')
    };
    function getItem(label, key, icon, children, role) {
        return {
            key,
            icon,
            children,
            label,
            role
        };
    }
    const items = [
        getItem("Kullanıcı Yönetimi", "sub1", <TeamOutlined />, [
            getItem(intl.formatMessage({ id: "menu_create_client" }), "menu_create_client", <UsergroupAddOutlined />, null, ["admin"]),
        ], ["admin"]),
        getItem("Sistem Ayarları", "sub2", <SettingOutlined />, [
            getItem(intl.formatMessage({ id: "menu_city_list" }), "menu_city_list", <AiOutlineMenu />,null,["admin","user"]),
            getItem(intl.formatMessage({ id: "menu_country_list" }), "menu_country_list", <AiOutlineMenu />,null,["admin","user"]),
            // getItem("Genel Ayarlar", "15", null, null, ["admin"]),
        ], ["admin","user"]),
        getItem("Hesabım", "sub3", <UserOutlined />, [
            getItem(intl.formatMessage({ id: "menu_my_account" }), "menu_my_account", <VscAccount />, null, ["admin","user"]),
            getItem(intl.formatMessage({ id: "menu_logout" }), "menu_logout", <LogoutOutlined />, null, ["admin","user"]),
        ], ["admin","user"]),
    ];
    const filteredItems = items.filter(item =>
        item.role && item.role.includes(userRole)
      );
      
      const finalItems = filteredItems.map(item => {
        if (!item.children) {
          return item;
        }
        const children = item.children.filter(child =>
          child.role && child.role.includes(userRole)
        );
        if (children.length === 0) {
          return null;
        }
        return {
          ...item,
          children
        };
      }).filter(Boolean);
      
    const handleButtonClick = (e) => {
        message.info('Click on left button.');
        console.log('click left button', e);
    };
    const handleMenuClick = (e) => {
        message.info('Click on menu item.');
        console.log('click', e);
    };

    return (
        <div>
            {loading ? (
                <Spin style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', height: '100vh' }} size="large" />
            ) : (
                <Layout
                    style={{
                        minHeight: "100vh",
                    }}
                >
                    <Sider
                        style={{
                            overflow: 'auto',
                            height: '100vh',
                            position: 'fixed',
                            left: 0,
                            top: 0,
                            bottom: 0,
                        }}
                        collapsible
                        collapsed={collapsed}
                        onCollapse={(value) => setCollapsed(value)}
                    >
                        <div
                            style={{
                                height: 32,
                                margin: 16,
                                background: "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8)",
                            }}
                        >
                        </div>
                        <Menu
                            theme="dark"
                            defaultSelectedKeys={[selectedMenu]}
                            defaultOpenKeys={[selectedSub]}
                            mode="inline"
                            items={finalItems}
                            onClick={menuItemClick}
                        />
                    </Sider>
                    <Layout className="site-layout"
                        >
                        <Content
                            style={{
                                margin: "0 16px",
                                overflow: 'initial'
                            }}
                        >
                            <Outlet/>
                            {/* </div> */}
                        </Content>
                    </Layout>
                </Layout>
            )}
        </div>
    );
}
```

```
import React from "react";
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';

import {
  Outlet,
  Navigate,
} from "react-router-dom";
import { getRole } from "../utils/HelperFunctions";

const PrivateRoutes = () => {
  const { userToken } = useSelector((state) => state.auth);
  const userRole = getRole(userToken);
  if (!userToken) {
    return <Navigate to="/login" replace />;
  }

  if (!userRole) {
    return <Navigate to="/" replace />;
  }

  return <Outlet />;
  //return userToken ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to="/login" replace />;
}


export default PrivateRoutes;
```

I created a Private Route and gave the page as a child, but I could not compare the role in the menu and the userRole in the private route component, so I can log in when I manually type it into the url.

Comment: This might help: https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-router-private-routes/